# What are the connected components of the real general linear group?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis

What are the connected components of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$? I think there are two, corresponding to those of positive and negative determinant. But I don’t know how to prove that each one of them is connected.

Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: For an answer see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3017861.

Comment: @PaulFrost thanks!